# Differences between xp_instance_RegRead and xp_RegRead

Tags: sql-server

Whats the difference between XP_REGREAD and XP_INSTANCE_REGREAD.
How to use them, is there any docs on these?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

xp_regread reads the literal registry path that you specify. xp_instance_regread "converts" the path you specify so that it matches the instance of SQL Server that you're currently using.

As an example, I have Developer and Express editions of SQL Server installed on my machine. I connect to the Express instance and run these two commands:

```
declare @dir nvarchar(4000) 

exec master.dbo.xp_regread 
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
    N'SQLPath',
    @dir output
select @dir

exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
    N'SQLPath', 
    @dir output
select @dir
```

The first returns `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` which is the value found at the location I specified but it is not the correct installation path for my Express instance.

The second returns `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL` which is the correct path for my Express instance. This value was actually read from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Setup` which is quite different from the path I supplied to xp_instance_regread.

Comment: I understood, thanks, I was getting mad at this, I then added admin rights to the account running SQL to have this right. Is there a way to read the registry without admin rights?

Comment: @Gabriel: You should be able to grant execute permission on the procedure.

Comment: But Do I need to have my SQL Service account have admin rights on the machine?

Comment: So long as you don't manually modify the windows service's launch settings to use a different account, the windows service will have read/write permissions on the instance registry keys.  Probably these permissions are configured when the keys are first created (i.e., during the initial configuration/install of SQL server).  Note that in many cases (including configuration changes made via SSMS), the values of these keys are ignored by SQL server until SQL Server is restarted.

Answer (score 3):

Gabriel, The Service account does not have to be dbo. As long as the user is a user in the master database, you can grant execute permissions on system objects in the master db.

```
GRANT EXEC ON OBJECT::master.dbo.xp_instance_regread TO ServiceAccountUserName
```

Comment: I was having a problem that I was trying to read the registry with a nvarchar(max) and it doesn't work like that, only with a number-sized char variable.