# How to access Server Properties in SQL Operations Studio?

Tags: t-sql, azure-data-studio

In **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, there is the option to right click on a server to get to: **Server Properties - Security**

What is the equivalent of that in the new **SQL Operations Studio** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does not fully answer the question, but here goes.

[image]

The Server properties -> Security is generated via querying the Windows Registry. There is no simple way to query it out of the system.

You can use

```
exec master.dbo.xp_regread 
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
    N'SQLPath',
    @dir output
select @dir

exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
    N'SQLPath', 
    @dir output
select @dir
```

The problem is, you have to know where in `N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',` to find what you are looking for.

This answer was based on: [Differences between xp_instance_RegRead and xp_RegRead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440141/differences-between-xp-instance-regread-and-xp-regread)

Comment: James, thanks for the reply. The **Server Properties - Security** screen you have shown looks like it is from **Management Studio**. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am looking for a way to do this interactively via **SSOP**. Perhaps there is a place where suggestions for **SSOP** can be requested ?